# Create a nested dictionary from a txt file

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, file-handling

Hi want to create a nested dictionary from a txt file.

The file looks this way:

> BTC 5 42
> ETH 0.2 1300

The expected result is this:

```html
crypto = {
    "c1" :
        {
            "name" : "BTC",
            "amount" : "5",
            "avalue" : "42000" 
        } ,
    "c2" :
        {
            "name" : "ETH",
            "amount" : "0.2",
            "avalue" : "2000" 
    }
```

How can I do this? I can also change the structure of the txt file and/or use an xlsx file

Comment: What is the logic behind converting 42->42000 and 1300->2000 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file contains:

```
BTC 5 42  
ETH 0.2 1300
```

then:

```py
crypto = {}
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    i = 1
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if line == "":
            continue
        name, amount, avalue = line.split()
        crypto[f"c{i}"] = {"name": name, "amount": amount, "avalue": avalue}
        i += 1

print(crypto)
```

creates `crypto` dictionary and prints:

```py
{
    "c1": {"name": "BTC", "amount": "5", "avalue": "42"},
    "c2": {"name": "ETH", "amount": "0.2", "avalue": "1300"},
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to produce to OP's required output

Comment: @LancelotduLac Gotcha. Let's wait for OP to clarify (might be just a typo).

Comment: that should work ty